# unable to convert groupby dataset to json in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have group by data set but I'm unable to convert it to json. It throws out json with a bad format. `TO_excel` works fine.

```
Country Sub amount        
        3   source4      
UK      1   source3      
        1   source1      
US      2   source2
```

How can I export groupby dataset to_json?

Comment: Maybe need `df = df.reset_index()` first.

Comment: There is `MultiIndex`? Can you explain more `bad format` ?

Comment: Would you mind describing your expected output? Also, print `df.head(5).to_dict()` here please.

Comment: @jezrael PLease type this- **df = df.reset_index()** as the answer. I'll accept it now!

Comment: Ohhh, no, sorry, it's a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem you have `MultiIndex` in `DataFrame`, so need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
j = df.reset_index().to_json()
print (j)
{"Country":{"0":"UK","1":"UK","2":"US"},
 "Sub":{"0":1,"1":1,"2":2},
 "amount":{"0":"source3","1":"source1","2":"source2"}}
```

Comment: Awesome! THanks J :)